# Определить плавный переход у градиента?

Tags: svg

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 400" width='1000' height='400' style='border:1px solid black'>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="80%" stop-color="yellow"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150" fill="url(#MyGradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Определить плавный переход у градиента можно по следующему алгоритму

1. От 0 до 20 будет красный цвет
2. от 80 до 100 будет желтый цвет
3. От 80 вычитаем 20 будет 60 - это плавный переход от красного цвета к желтому верно ?

Comment: у градиента в svg ещё есть параметры и это не только stop и stop-color ещё и x1 x2 y1 y2 то есть некие координаты начала и конца градиента а так же stop-opacity и если в градиенте есть цвет который надо размыть (только без фанатизма) надо воспользоваться stop-opacity...если что то не ясно спрашивай

Comment: Вот пример с твоим градиентом: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/abddZxp

Comment: и так же ещё параметр: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientUnits

Comment: @MaximLensky  ок спасибо